# First letter in INPUT doesn't show up in $().keydown of jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am stuck with this for hours and I cant figure it out why is that when I enter a letter in  the input and call the $().keydown of jQuery and **alert** it with the `$(this).val()`, the first letter that I inputted won't show up but when you input a letter again it shows up.

Is there any explanation for this?

```
<div class="mainboxforfriendfind">
    <div class="findfriend">
        <input type="text" id="findtext" name="friendfinder" placeholder="Enter Text to find a friend"/>
        <button id="buttonfriend" class="findfriendbutton"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="outputfindfriend">  
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $("#findtext").keydown(function () {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use keyup instead of keydown

```
$("#findtext").keyup(function () {

    alert($(this).val());

});
```

Comment: Wow you are a life saver been looking for the answer for hours and keyup was just the answer all along. Thank you very much sir,